# Array_merge unknown amount of arrays as variable variables

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Thanks for helping as always.

My code generates arrays in the following format

```
${'readyformerge' . $b} = $temparraytwo;
```

Which results in the array names of

```
$readyformerge1
$readyformerge2
$readyformerge3
```

etc...

Which works well and we know the value that $b holds is the amount of arrays we need to merge. However I can't quite see how to do this when we won't know prior to running the script how many arrays will be created.

Fundamentally I would like to use the following to grab the result but as you see I can only do this for the amount of results I THINk it will return NOT the actual number of results. Any help?

```
$outputmultidimensionalevent = array_merge_recursive(${'readyformerge' . $b},${'readyformerge' . $b});
print_r($outputmultidimensionalevent); echo '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the result of bad design.

Instead of:

```
${'readyformerge' . $b} = $temparraytwo;
```

You should do something like this:

```
$readyformerge[$b] = $temparraytwo;
```

And then:

```
$merged = array();

foreach ($readyformerge as $one) {
    $merged = array_merge($merged, $one);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bodgan, I've explained slightly further below. You have certainly pointed me in the right direction so far!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, That's pushed me in the right direction.

So currently it's now setup like this:

```
    $z=1;
    $readyformergemulti = array();
    while ($z <= $i){
    array_push($readyformergemulti,${'readyformerge' . $z});
    $z++;
    }
    foreach ($readyformergemulti as $one) {
        print_r($one);
        echo '<br/>';
    $merged = array_merge_recursive($merged, $one);
    }
    print_r($readyformergemulti); echo '<br/>';
    print_r($merged); echo '<br/>';
```

But unfortunately $merged returns nothing. If you look at the following the first 4 lines are the $readyformerge arrays and the 5th line is the desired result:

```
Array ( [house] => 2797 ) 
Array ( [house] => 2829 ) 
Array ( [house] => 2736 )
Array ( [electronica] => 2763 [house] => 2763 ) 
Array ( [electronica] => Array (2763) [house] => Array (2763,2797,2892,2736 ) )
```

Sorry to be a pain, and I KNOW everyone needs to see more code, but with thousands of lines it gets hard to display!

If you can help again that would be great!